# How to delete a row using the value from 2 columns?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[this is the image of my POS ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjSlB.png)

```
itemIDV = itemIdVoid.Text; //this is where i input my sequence no
if (itemIDV == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Sequence Number");
}
else
{
    voidPanel.Hide();
    for (int v = 0; v < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; v++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(dataGridView2[0, v].Value as string, itemIDV))
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(v);
            v--;
```

For now i can only delete a row using the Sequence number column and what i want is how to delete a row using Sequence combined with Stock number? Like if i want to void the "Laptop" i will input "1606" (the combination of seqNo. and StockNo.) Thank you.

Comment: Generally, you should crawl backwards in your loop to avoid that index position problem you are trying to overcome with the `v--;` line.  For your sequence problem, not sure why you don't just combine the two columns for your string when you are comparing.

Comment: Have you thought about what should happen if `seqNo. + stockNo.` is the same as a standalone `seqNo.`?

Comment: Note that **Removing** a row from a DGV is not the same as **Deleting** a row.  Generally it is preferred to use a DataSource and let the DB Provider objects do all the work.

Comment: You can do something like: `var row = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells["seqNo"].ToString() == "1" && r.Cells["StockNo"].ToString() == "606"); if (row != null) dgv.Rows.Remove(row);`